# It is not inserting a date in the database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php/Mysql query with inserting date fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793893/php-mysql-query-with-inserting-date-fails)

I have a datepicker code below:

```
         $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: 0, 
                            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
});
```

As you can see the format of the date when it is displayed in the datepicker textbox ('dateChosen') is 'dd-mm-yy' which is like this (20-05-2012).

But when I try and insert the date in the 'SessionDate' field, instead of displaying '2012-05-20' in the database, it keeps displaying '0000-00-00'. Why is it doing this?

What I want is the textbox format to remain the same but when the date is inserted into the SessionDate table, then I want it inserted as '2012-05-20' and not as '0000-00-00'.

Below is code for the insert ($_POST['dateChosen'] is the post method which posts the date):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Session (SessionDate)
VALUES
(' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dateChosen'] ) . "'
)";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What's in `$_POST['dateChosen']`?

Comment: datepicker is the calender which appears while dateChosen is the textbox where the date (20-05-2012') is displayed

Comment: what is the data type for column SessionDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dateformat is `dd-mm-yy`, so the date will be of the type: `31-03-12` and not `31-03-2012`. MySQL can't accept that value in its dateformat syntax. Try this in insert query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionDate) VALUES(' " .
       mysql_real_escape_string( date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['dateChosen'] ) ) ) . "')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: suprisingly dd-mm-yy is actually displaying '20-05-2012' and not what you stated lol, strange ! I really test your answer and get back to you

Comment: @user1298892 Either way, MySQL's default date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. So your query will surely fail.

Comment: Thank you this has worked well :), can I ask you a quick question, If I have the same situation with time, then do I just do similay code you have mentioned but instead of 'Y-m-d', change it to 'h-m-s'?

Comment: @user1298892, no. For time, you'll have to change it to `date("H:i:s", <rest>`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) -

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateChosen']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionDate) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d-%m-%y'))";
mysql_query($sql);
```